# Which other languages/IDEs are setup like iPhone/Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, model-view-controller, ide

In know the question isn't exactly programming related but I think this forum is the best place to ask.  So, with risk of the question being pulled, here goes...

What other languages/IDEs are setup as well as the iPhone with Xcode and Interface Builder? Apple uses one design pattern and uses it extremely well - MVC.  IB doesn't have any code.  It's all UI and that enforces the pattern.   By contrast, .NET and Visual Studio fail miserably to separate UI and code.  Even XAML with Blend doesn't get any better.

Does any one else (languages/IDEs) do it as well as Apple?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found one that really comes close. You might want to try looking at [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) from Trolltech. I liked their Designer tool in previous versions and [Creator](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-1.1/index.html) looks pretty promising.

Comment: That's pretty cool.  From what I can tell, there's no code behind.  It's all GUI with their designer.  Is that only for C++ and Cocoa?

Comment: I've only used their (Qt's) C++ tools. There is some code lurking in the background. Their tools allow you to connect what they call "slots and signals" and then write the C++ that implements a response to a slot. It's been a number of years, but that is how I remember it working. Their slots and signals are analogous to the IBOutlet stuff in Objective C. It is pretty much a domain specific language that Trolltech created... pretty neat stuff, but not quite as nice as Objective C is IMHO.

Comment: I believe qt has a ui compiler uic which it runs on the xml file representing the ui and turns it into c++ code.